# Can I use xamarin ios page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

My question as the title, I have done that in android using xamarin message center
and I want to know if it is possible for IOS too especially I a beginner IOS developer.

So what I want is to go from xamarin forms page to ios page or the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a native iOS or Android page/control to Forms by using a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).

Comment: Thank you for your response jason but I prefer to use native xamarin if it is possible because it is easier in some things like showing map and that is because it has toturials more and I dont know why I get many errors in forms that is not coming in the native.

Comment: Maybe you can look for components which are already there in nuget doing whatevery you are trying to do

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do.  You asked about using native UI in Forms - Renderers are the way to do that.  If you're having a specific problem in Forms, then you should ask about that problem.  If you have been able to solve your problem in Android, the same general approach should work on iOS too.

Comment: Thank you guys I found what I were looking for here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native